# Simple SAT Solver In Python

Tags: python

I am interested in improving my coding standards in Python so I decided to post one my more recent and smaller "for fun" projects here for review. The code below implements a rather simple backtracking algorithm to solve SAT, which is based on Knuth's SAT0W found here: http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/programs.html (While the algorithm is essentially the same as Knuth's, my implementation is heavily simplified compared to Knuth's.)

While I appreciate all feedback, I am more interested in improvements that are Python- or implementation-specific, as opposed to algorithmic improvements, since I know there are many ways of improving the algorithm, as discussed by Knuth as well, which I left out of the code in favour of simplicity and ease of understanding.

First, the command-line driver:

```
"""
Solve SAT instance by reading from stdin using an iterative or recursive
watchlist-based backtracking algorithm. Iterative algorithm is used by default,
unless the -r flag is given.
"""
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from argparse import ArgumentParser
from sys import stdin
from sys import stderr

from satinstance import SATInstance
import recursive_sat
import iterative_sat

__author__ = 'Sahand Saba'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
    parser.add_argument('-v',
                        '--verbose',
                        help='verbose output.',
                        action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-r',
                        '--recursive',
                        help='use the recursive backtracking algorithm.',
                        action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-i',
                        '--input',
                        help='read from given file instead of stdin.',
                        action='store')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    instance = None
    if args.input:
        with open(args.input, 'r') as file:
            instance = SATInstance.from_file(file)
    else:
        instance = SATInstance.from_file(stdin)

    alg = recursive_sat.solve if args.recursive else iterative_sat.solve
    for assignment in alg(instance, args.verbose):
        print(instance.assignment_to_string(assignment))
    else:
        if args.verbose:
            print('No satisfying assignment exists.', file=stderr)
```

The `satinstance.py` file:

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

__author__ = 'Sahand Saba'


class SATInstance(object):
    def _parse_and_add_clause(self, line):
        """
        Some notes on encoding:
        - Variables are encoded as numbers 0 to n - 1.
        - Literal v is encoded as 2 * v and ~v as 2 * v + 1. So the foremost
          bit of a literal encodes whether it is negated or not. This can be
          tested simply with checking if l & 1 is 0 or 1.
        - Similarly, to negate a literal, we just have to toggle the foremost
          bit.  This can done easily by XORing with 1: the negation l is l ^ 1.
        - To get a literal's variable, we just need to shift to the right. This
          can be done with either l >> 1.

        Example: Let's say variable b is encoded with number 3. Then literal b
        is encoded as 2 * 3 = 6 and ~b as  2 * 3 + 1 = 7.
        """
        clause = []
        for literal in line.split():
            negated = 1 if literal.startswith('~') else 0
            variable = literal[negated:]
            if variable not in self.variable_table:
                self.variable_table[variable] = len(self.variables)
                self.variables.append(variable)
            encoded_literal = self.variable_table[variable] << 1 | negated
            clause.append(encoded_literal)
        self.clauses.append(tuple(set(clause)))

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, file):
        instance = cls()
        instance.variables = []
        instance.variable_table = dict()
        instance.clauses = []
        for line in file:
            instance._parse_and_add_clause(line)
        instance.n = len(instance.variables)
        return instance

    def literal_to_string(self, literal):
        s = '~' if literal & 1 else ''
        return s + self.variables[literal >> 1]

    def clause_to_string(self, clause):
        return ' '.join(self.literal_to_string(l) for l in clause)

    def assignment_to_string(self, assignment):
        return ' '.join(v if assignment[i] else '~' + v
                        for i, v in enumerate(self.variables)
                        if assignment[i] is not None)
```

And the iterative algorithm:

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from watchlist import setup_watchlist
from watchlist import update_watchlist

__author__ = 'Sahand Saba'


def solve(instance, verbose=False):
    watchlist = setup_watchlist(instance)
    if not watchlist:
        return

    # The state list wil keep track of what values for which variables
    # we have tried so far. A value of 0 means nothing has been tried yet,
    # a value of 1 means False has been tried but not True, 2 means True but
    # not False, and 3 means both have been tried.
    state = [0] * instance.n
    assignment = [None] * instance.n
    d = 0  # Current depth in the backtrack tree
    while True:
        if d == instance.n:
            yield assignment
            d -= 1
            continue
        # Let's try assigning a value to v. Here would be the place to insert
        # heuristics of which value to try first.
        tried_something = False
        for a in [0, 1]:
            if (state[d] >> a) & 1 == 0:
                tried_something = True
                # Set the bit indicating a has been tried for d
                state[d] |= 1 << a
                assignment[d] = a
                if not update_watchlist(instance, watchlist,
                                        d << 1 | 1 ^ a,
                                        assignment,
                                        verbose):
                    assignment[d] = None
                else:
                    d += 1
                    break

        if not tried_something:
            if d == 0:
                # Can't backtrack further. No solutions.
                return
            else:
                # Backtrack
                state[d] = 0
                assignment[d] = None
                d -= 1
```

I'm skipping a few of the files like `watchlist.py` and `recursive_sat.py`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This review will focus on **the command-line driver**. Others will no doubt elaborate on the rest of your code.

### Piece-by-piece review

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

The Python convention is to **extract everything that follows into a function**, enabling you to better organize your code. This allows you to call functions defined further down rather than only ones defined above.

```
    parser = ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
    parser.add_argument('-v',
                        '--verbose',
                        help='verbose output.',
                        action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-r',
                        '--recursive',
                        help='use the recursive backtracking algorithm.',
                        action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-i',
                        '--input',
                        help='read from given file instead of stdin.',
                        action='store')
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

This arg-parsing code should be extracted as a function that [**does one thing, does it well, and does it only**](http://blog.codinghorror.com/curlys-law-do-one-thing/).

```
    instance = None
    if args.input:
        with open(args.input, 'r') as file:
            instance = SATInstance.from_file(file)
    else:
        instance = SATInstance.from_file(stdin)

    alg = recursive_sat.solve if args.recursive else iterative_sat.solve
```

If you read the [`argparse` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html#action) more carefully, you will notice that you are not using its full capabilities. You can simplify this part of your program  considerably if you let the `ArgumentParser` store the appropriate implementation of your algorithm directly. It can also handle the optional input file opening for you, falling back to `stdin` if none is supplied.

```
    for assignment in alg(instance, args.verbose):
        print(instance.assignment_to_string(assignment))
    else:
        if args.verbose:
            print('No satisfying assignment exists.', file=stderr)
```

The `else` branch of this `for` loop [does not do what you think it does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/114420/1106367), so **here's your bug**:

> Your program will *always* print the error message because the `else` branch of a `for` loop is always executed unless a `break` statement terminates the loop.

## Improved code

```
def main():
    args = parse_args()
    with args.input as file:
        instance = SATInstance.from_file(file)
    result = args.algorithm.solve(instance, args.verbose)
    for assignment in result:
        print(instance.assignment_to_string(assignment))
    if not result and args.verbose:
        print('No satisfying assignment exists.', file=stderr)


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose',
                        help='verbose output.',
                        action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--recursive',
                        help='use the recursive backtracking algorithm.',
                        action='store_const',
                        dest='algorithm',
                        const=recursive_sat,
                        default=iterative_sat)
    parser.add_argument('-i', '--input',
                        help='read from given file instead of stdin.',
                        type=argparse.FileType(),  # opens the supplied file
                        default=stdin)
    return parser.parse_args()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. Just one subtle correction to your suggestion: `type=FileType()` should be `type=FileType` without the `()` since otherwise it will throw an exception saying `FileType` requires one parameter.

Comment: On second thought, I realized you had `argparse.FileType` in mind, whereas my first thought was that it was `types.FileType`, which is the only `FileType` I knew about! With `argparse.FileType` you need the `()`. So your code is correct for Python 2 as well.

Comment: @Sahand ah, that makes sense. Sorry for the confusion, I should have included the full name.